# Duda con expresión regular

Tags: regex

Estoy iniciándome en los regex y no consigo hacer una captura basada en este texto:

```
ASIN ‏ : ‎ B09RLXVHSB Editorial ‏ : ‎ Independently published (30 enero 2022) Idioma ‏ : ‎ Español Tapa blanda ‏ : ‎ 102 páginas ISBN-13 ‏ : ‎ 979-8410369077 Edad de lectura ‏ : ‎ De 1 a 12 años Peso del producto ‏ : ‎ 327 g Dimensiones ‏ : ‎ 21.59 x 0.58 x 27.94 cm
```

Lo que necesito es capturar el idioma (en este caso Español).

He probado con esta expresión en entre otras muchas pero no doy con la tecla:

`Idioma\s+:\s+([A-Z]+)\s+Tapa`

Answer (score 1):

Pegando tu texto tal cual en [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) me aparece un símbolo unicode repetido constantemente entre los espacios, que está escondido y no se ve, que es el ‏`U+200E‏`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si los quitas verás que la expresión empieza a funcionar. Al final a mi me ha funcionado así:

```
Idioma\s+:\s+[a-zA-Zñ]*
```

Si no quieres limpiar el texto unicode **antes** del regex, entonces prueba esta otra cadena de regex ([ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/JHEvS1/1)):

```
Idioma\s\X\s:\s\X\s[a-zA-Zñ]*
```

o si estas usando .NET, Java 8 o anteriores, o Ruby 1.9 esta cadena parece la adecuada ([ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/oR8cln/1)):

```
Idioma\s(?>\P{M}\p{M}*)\s:\s(?>\P{M}\p{M}*)\s[a-zA-Zñ]*
```

donde:

- **\X** o también **(?>\P{M}\p{M}*)** representa una coincidencia simple de un grafema unicode, tal como reza [esta documentación](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html?#grapheme).

Comment: Gracias. tienes razón no se de donde salen esos caracteres pero la información me viene así y no puedo cambiarlo.

Comment: Bueno después de una hora dándole a posibles soluciones, no he conseguido nada. ¿De que forma podría incluir esos unicode para hacer mi captura?

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. Pensaba que ibas a eliminar el unicode antes del regex, pero veo que lo quieres todo en regex, pues a ver si así te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Mis dos centavos.

Intenta con esta regex:

```
Idioma[^:]+:(\X|\s){3}\K(\X+?)(?=\s+)
```

Me funcionó con las expresiones regulares tipo Perl para `grep`.

Por ejemplo, aquí utilicé caracteres no latinos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La descripción de la Regex es:

- `Idioma` -> la palabra idioma
- `[^:]+` -> lo que no sean dos puntos, y repetido múltiples veces
- `:` -> los dos puntos
- `(\X|\s){3}` -> 3 veces la coincidencia de un caracter unicode, o de un espacio
- `\K` -> Olvida todo lo anterior
- `(\X+?)` -> Cualquier secuencia de caracteres unicode pero que no sea greedy
- `(?=\s+)` -> Y que este antes de múltiples espacios